# WordPress page leave too much space

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a WordPress page where I set up a row with main side at span10 and the right sidebar at span2. However, the page leaves more blank space, for example, you scroll to the right and see nothing. Here is the [page in question](https://qwick.info/GoldTaurus/2018/11/01/hello-world/)

Here is the single.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="span10">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><em><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></em></p>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <hr>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<div class="span2">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm also wondering if this may be more of a WordPress issue instead of HTML, I'm a rookie with WordPress Theme Development, this is a BootStrap site.

Comment: Your rendered HTML seems to be invalid. Run it through a validator like https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri. Might just be an unclosed tag

Comment: Removing the `1170px` width that you are giving in bootstrap-responsive.css on line 133 corrects the layout though.

Answer (score 1):

your span8 insde span2, gets **width:770px** from bootstrap-responsive.css and overrides **width:620px** from bootstrap.css.

span4 width looks fine for this occasion (which is only 370px) but not span8.

**TLDR;** Try to remove (or change class) `<div class="span8"></div>` which you get from `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` which is located inside `<div class="span2">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I thank everyone for the help.

I was going along with this [page here].[1](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial)

After trying a few things and also not finding the unclosed div I was looking for, I surrendered and went to the end of that page (before the comments) and downloaded the finished project. Interestingly, it did NOT include the single.php file, that is when I ran into trouble with the said problem.

I imagine they made a mistake with the code and decided not to add it on the final project zip files, or I made the mistake. Chances are good it was the latter.

However, I was working with another WordPress project that worked well with the single.php, so that page helped out with that, but not this.

Thanks again.